# How to start on ServiceStack?

Tags: asp.net-core, servicestack

Can you help me point out how should I start on this:

I'm new to API , and I'm currently working on ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC paired with Microsoft SQL Server. I have requirement that I should use API (ServiceStack) for a certain method.

My question are :

- how or where do I start from my existing project solution?
- If I use API should it be calling on SQL also? *(I supposed the data will stay on db)*
- *with regards to first question* : they gave me a link where I can see this.
  [image: Link]

Where should I start , I'm just so confused.

I've looked up on youtube but there's no similar case to mine, they all use in-memory.
Suggestions and advice are welcome !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through ServiceStack's Getting Started Section starting with [Create your first Web Service](https://docs.servicestack.net/create-your-first-webservice).

#### Configure OrmLite in your AppHost

To configure OrmLite, start with the [OrmLite Installation](https://docs.servicestack.net/ormlite/installation) tells you which package to download whilst the [OrmLite Getting Started](https://docs.servicestack.net/ormlite/getting-started) docs lists all the available [SQL Server Dialects](https://docs.servicestack.net/ormlite/getting-started#sql-server-dialects) which you'd use to configure the [OrmLiteConnectionFactory](https://docs.servicestack.net/ormlite/getting-started#ormlite-connection-factory) in your IOC.

E.g. for SQL Server 2012:

```cs
public class AppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public AppHost() : base("MyApp", typeof(MyServices).Assembly) { }

    // Configure your ServiceStack AppHost and App dependencies
    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
         container.AddSingleton<IDbConnectionFactory>(
            new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connectionString, 
            SqlServer2012Dialect.Provider));
    }
}
```

#### Using OrmLite in Services

Then inside your ServiceStack Services you can access your ADO .NET DB connection via `base.Db` which you can use with [OrmLite's extension methods](https://docs.servicestack.net/ormlite/apis/select), e.g:

```cs
public class MyServices : Service
{
    public object Any(GetAllItems request) => new GetAllItemsResponse {
        Results = Db.Select<Item>()
    };
}
```

> Checkout the [OrmLite APIs](https://docs.servicestack.net/ormlite/apis/select) docs for different APIs to Select, Insert, Update & Delete Data.

#### Creating effortless RDBMS APIs using AutoQuery

As you're new I'd highly recommend using [AutoQuery RDBMS](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms) since it lets you create RDBMS APIs with just Request DTOs.

You can enable it by adding the `AutoQueryFeature` plugin in the **ServiceStack.Server"** NuGet package:

```cs
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    Plugins.Add(new AutoQueryFeature { MaxLimit = 100 });
}
```

Then you can create an AutoQuery API for your `Item` table with just:

```cs
[Route("/items")]
public class QueryItems : QueryDb<Item> {}
```

Which will now let you query each Item column using any of [AutoQuery's implicit conventions](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms#implicit-conventions), e.g by exact match:

```
/items?Id=1
```

Or by any of the query properties:

```
/items?NameStartsWith=foo
```

#### Creating Typed Request DTO

Once you know which Query APIs your client Apps needs I'd recommend formalizing them by adding them as strong typed properties in your Request DTO, e.g:

```cs
[Route("/items")]
public class QueryItems : QueryDb<Item> 
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string NameStartsWith { get; set; }
}
```

#### Calling from Service Clients

Which will enable an end-to-end Typed API using any of [ServiceStack's Service Clients](https://docs.servicestack.net/clients-overview), e.g:

```cs
var client = new JsonServiceClient(BaseUrl);

var response = client.Get(new QueryItems { NameStartsWith = "foo" });

response.PrintDump(); // quickly view results in Console
```

There's also [AutoQuery CRUD APIs](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-crud) that will let you create APIs that modify your RDBMS tables using just Request DTOs.

Comment: can you help me ,I can't run a project cause I received a warning during creating a new project `INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern
'npm' not found in PATH, skipping npm install.`    I just followed the first example on documentation :   ` x new web WebApp`

Comment: @JohnPhillipAbello that's an npm problem which sounds like you either don't have node.js installed or it's not resolvable in your System path. I'd try re-installing node.js to see if it fixes it first, otherwise post a new question with your node.js issue

Comment: I've already installed node.js and servicestack vs extension but I'm still getting `Installing mvc...
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).`

Comment: @JohnPhillipAbello It's a local system issue, can't help you. If it says 'npm' not found in PATH, it means just that, i.e. it can't find npm which comes installed with node.js in your system path. Either way this is unreleated to this issue, post a new question - maybe someone else can help you

Comment: after I installed npm the warning ` 'npm' not found in PATH` disappears but this warning `INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).` still shows.

Comment: @JohnPhillipAbello that error message isn't useful without context, please post a new question, last time I'm saying it.